# parsing big XML file and inserting data to SQL server in vb

Tags: vb.net

I need to parse an XML file and store the data to sql server in vb.net. I have been reading online and it seems that I should use xmltextReader class to read the file, since this will eliminate the out of memory issue. I started something like following. I need feedback that am I doing OK or should I used some other way that will be easier. Sample XML file goes like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MainElement>
    <MainEle1>
        <InfoA>
            <InfoAId>121480431A</InfoAId>
            <firstName>Anne</firstName>
            <lastName>Stevens</lastName>
            <phone>6023122456</phone>
            <address>
                <address1>8735 Elm Road</address1>
                <address2></address2>
                <city>Nowhere</city>
                <country></country>
                <state>CA</state>
                <suite></suite>
                <zipCode>30141</zipCode>
            </address>
            <dob>09/08/1982</dob>
            <gender></gender>
            <primaryLanguage>Other</primaryLanguage>
            <otherLanguage>french</otherLanguage>
            <planName></planName>
            <contacts>
                <firstName>rajesh</firstName>
                <lastName>raj</lastName>
                <phone>1232343241</phone>
                <address>
                    <address1></address1>
                    <address2></address2>
                    <city></city>
                    <country></country>
                    <state></state>
                    <suite></suite>
                    <zipCode></zipCode>
                </address>
                <contactType>EMERGENCY</contactType>
                <relationship>friend</relationship>
                <typeDesc>Emergency Contact/Next of Kin</typeDesc>
            </contacts>
         </InfoA>
    </MainEle1>
    <MainEle2>
        <subMainEle2>
            <firstName>victor</firstName>
            <lastName>john</lastName>
            <phone>1233455678</phone>
            <address>
                <address1>123 arrow</address1>
                <address2></address2>
                <city>upland</city>
                <country></country>
                <state>ca</state>
                <suite>234</suite>
                <zipCode>76547</zipCode>
            </address>
            <contactType>PRIMARY</contactType>
            <relationship></relationship>
            <typeDesc></typeDesc>
        </subMainEle2>
    </MainEle2>
    <MainEle3>
    ..
    </MailEle3>
    <MainEle4>
    ..
    </MailEle4>
    ..
</MainElement>

Dim reader As XmlTextReader
reader = New XmlTextReader("c:\FileName")

While Not reader.EOF
    Select Case reader.NodeType
    Case XmlNodeType.Element 
        Select Case reader.Name
        Case "MainEle1"
            Call ProcessMainEle1(reader) ' passing reader as ref
        Case "MainEle2"
            call ProcessMainEle2(reader) ' passing reader as ref
        Case "MainEle3"
            call ProcessMainEle3(reader) 'passing reader as ref
                 ' and read many element
        End Select
    End Select
End While
```

and in Process method I am using similar approach and creating the insert statement.
Is that the right approach or is there a simple approach for large file with many element within elements. I would appreciate guidance for novice programmer

Comment: Does your code do what you need? Does it do it fast **enough**? if both yes - than your approach is good. Otherwise add information on what you need to improve (and for simple code review SO is not the right place - try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case It is important to use an XML Parser which is not DOM based. (SAXParser)

From memory consumption point of view there is nothing worse in IT than a DOM based XML parser. Such a parser will need 100 - 1000 times more memory than a low level parsing, which is more work for you.

Comment: @alexei-- I started this approach, but I was looking for a better approach, since I am reading every element and if matches then I process the information. I have big file to process, but I started with small chunks, so far looks goods, but not sure what will happened when I will load the whole file.

Comment: --what do you mean by xml parser? I think xmltextreader is providing xml parsing capabilities. I was looking for better example on net or should I used this or use xpath approach

Comment: roughlly, there are two types of XML Parsers technics: DOM based and Sax parser based. DOM based parsers build up a huge object tree exactly representing your xml file, but using 100 time more memory than the elements would need if you would pare it yourself. Then ther are Sax based parser, they call you when thy read a new value from the xml file, you have then to decide where to store it. So check how xmltextreader internaly works, if DOm based or SAX.